# LINQ to SQL group people by age

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

> Sample in C# and VB.NET are OK.

I have a table "People" with the following columns:

-FullName (nvarchar not null)
-DOB (datetime null)

I want to write a LINQ to SQL to group the people by age, like following result:

Age 19: 4 ppl

Age 20: 5 ppl

Age 21: 6 ppl

and so on...

Here's my try:

```
Dim query = From ppl In db.People _
         Select New With {.Age = DateTime.Now.Year - CDate(ppl.DOB).Year, .CountAge = ppl.Count}
```

Notice that there are no DOB record for some people in the tables, so these shall not be included. The DOB column has record like this 1982-10-24 10:12:45 AM because it's a DateTime column.

Comment: "Notice that there are DOB record for some people in the tables..." Are you missing a word in that sentence?

Comment: It should be " there no DOB record for some people". Yes, I didn't type the word "no". Thx.

Comment: There are a couple of problems for starters: `.Age = DateTime.Now.Year - CDate(ppl.DOB).Year` will get the wrong age much of the time (consider where the birthdate occurs in the year). Also you've got no aggregating there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather:

```
var result = db.People
  .Where(p => p.DOB != null) // exclude null DOB's from stats
  .GroupBy(p => p.DOB.Value.Year)
  .Select(g => new { Age = DateTime.Now.Year - g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

We are grouping against year of birth here. This should translate to `GROUP BY YEAR(dob)` in SQL which could have slightly better performance or optimization compared to `GROUP BY YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(dob)`. It's almost impossible to map row expressions into indexes but certain constructs like `YEAR()` alone could be optimized to use a datetime index partially. I make many assumptions here though, like that `datetime` structures start with year, SQL server cares about `YEAR(x)` for optimizations etc. It's still good to keep in mind such situations when constructing a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

More accurate solution:

```
db.People.Where(p => p.DOB != null).GroupBy(p => ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.DOB, DateTime.Today) / 365)))
.Select(g => new {Age=g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

to group into intervals:

```
var interval = 5; //years
db.People.Where(p => p.DOB != null).GroupBy(p => ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.DOB, DateTime.Today) / 365) / interval))
.Select(g => new {GroupIndex=g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using EF Core 3.1 DbFunctions has been replaced with EF.Functions.
As another alternative you could use this:

```
var query = await db.People
                 .GroupBy(x.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? (int)(EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.DateOfBirth.Value, DateTime.UtcNow) / 365.25) : (int?)null)
                  .Select(x => new
                  {
                      Age = x.Key,
                      Count = x.Count(),
                  })
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

It takes the 'Birth day' into consideration, not the time but is more accurate than using only the 'Birth year'

Answer (score 0):

```
From ppl In db.People
Select New With {.Age = DateTime.Now.Year - CDate(ppl.DOB).Year, 
                 .CountAge = ppl.Count()}
Group By (DateTime.Now.Year - CDate(ppl.DOB).Year)
```

I think this query will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DOB is a nullable DateTime (DateTime?), so no DOB record would mean null there:

```
  from ppl in db.People
  where ppl.DOB.HasValue
  let age = DateTime.Today.Year - ppl.DOB.Value.Year 
  group ppl by age into ages
  select new { Age=ages.Key, Persons = ages  }
```

This is in C# but should translate well to VB since the syntax is similar.

Comment: If two people were born in January and December, would they not still have the same age with your query?

Comment: Indeed, this is merely a bad approximation, but following the logic OP is using. His question was about the grouping so I wanted to keep it like his :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (and should calculate ages a little more accurately):

```
var query = from person in db.People
            where person.DOB.HasValue
            let age = (DateTime.Now - username.UpdateDateTime.Value).Days % 365
            group person by age into ages
            select new { Age =ages.Key, People = ages.Count() }
```